# Shuffle slide in Divi Wordpress

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I have a full screen slide using Divi on Wordpress. How can I make shuffle for the people not see the same image every time they enter on the website? Thanks!!

Comment: give us some codes ... for example the js code for the slider ...

Comment: @MajidNayyeri Yes, I'm sorry [link](https://jsbin.com/kulegowuna/edit?js)

Comment: @MajidNayyeri I added HTML code :)

Answer (score 6):

Jakuya

I think this code will help you. Just go to to *divi > theme option > integration tab > Add code to the < head > of your blog* and paste in the code below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  var item = document.querySelector('.et_pb_slider .et_pb_slides');
  if(item!=null){
    for (var i = item.children.length; i >= 0; i--) {
      item.appendChild(item.children[Math.random() * i | 0]);
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

Try this , and let me know the result, if it works.